# VBA if a specific columns and rows are selected, Type Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code where sub activates when I select a specific column and specific row but gives me a type mismatch error on the following code:

```
If Selection.Worksheet.Columns("E:L") And Selection.Worksheet.Rows("16:99999") Then
```

Answer (score 1):

You will see that the keyword Target always returns the Range Object of the cell that fired the Worksheet_Change Event. So, armed with this knowledge we can now use the Intersect Method to take some action when/if  specified cell is changed. For example;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E12:L54787")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You, that helped, Another question for you, where can I learn all this logic and code? I am trying to learn as I go and I am struggling and making a lot of mistakes

Comment: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-intersect-union.htm https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/union-intersect.html and GOOGLE

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in the corresponding worksheet:

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Columns("E:L")) Is Nothing) And _
        (Not Intersect(Target, Rows("16:99999")) Is Nothing) Then

        Debug.Print Target.Address

    End If

End Sub
```

- [Selection.Change documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange)
- [Application.Intersect method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)